# Unable to login to Keystone with remote MongoDB

Tags: mlab, keystonejs

I am trying to set up a keystone project with a remote database server hosted on mLab. I am using this guide here https://itnext.io/building-a-node-cms-with-keystonejs-mongo-db-react-and-redux-part-i-ae5958496df2

I have edited the mongo url in the keystone.init() configuration, with my mLab database URL, and managed to run the project.

```
'mongo': 'mongodb://*username*:*password*@ds127624.mlab.com:27624/keystone',
```

However, I am unable to login as a user.

The login page returned:
"The email and password you entered are not valid."

Do I need to do some more configurations for it to work properly?

....

user.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var User = new keystone.List('User');

User.add({
  name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, index: true },
  email: { type: Types.Email, initial: true, required: true, index: true },
  password: { type: Types.Password, initial: true },
  canAccessKeystone: { type: Boolean, initial: true },
});

User.register();
```

0.0.01-admin.js file

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var User = keystone.list('User');

exports = module.exports = function (done) {
    new User.model({
        name: { first: 'admin', last: 'user' },
        email: 'admin@keystonejs.com',
        password: 'admin',
        canAccessKeystone: true,
    }).save(done);

};
```

Comment: Please provide more info like mongo url(remove username and password), or what configuration you tried, what error you are getting, it will help SO members to address your query.

Answer (score 0):

For remote database with password you also have to add `authsource` option. basically add **?authSource=admin** to your mongo url. `admin` is default db, you can change that as well

`mongodb://*username*:*password*@ds127624.mlab.com:27624/keystone?authSource=admin`